NextJS app router - get all query parameters in string
I thought this would be easy but I am struggling greatly.
I have a page with multiple query params:
/pathname?param1=lorem&param2=ipsum&param3=dolor&param4=sit

All I want is to be able to use this string in my component:
param1=lorem&param2=ipsum&param3=dolor&param4=sit
How to do this?

is it a server component

maybe this will help if server componeny https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional

client component for now!

If you're on the client you can typically use the useSearchParms hook from next/navigation.
If you're on the backend you can use the request object.
Here are some examples:
Client
The client has a hook provided by Next.js. Read the docs here.
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}


The code above is directly from the documentation.

You should consult the request object docs via MDN for details on using that directly, e.g. req.url.
Backend
For the full string use the url and/or pull the request parameters from that url using .get.
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    const reqUrl = req.url
    const { searchParams } = new URL(reqUrl)
    console.log(searchParams.get("param1")) // should print lorem
}


Thanks for your answer! It is a client component (I guess :') mostly cause I really dont understand how to implement the second example). i had found the first option but it only gets one specific queryparameter, I want to have the entire thing (can be more than 10) in one string. Is that also possible ?

@Santi try searchParams.toString() or .entries()

searchParams.toString() Worked!! Dont know why I couldn't find that. Thank you so so much!!

@Santi you can find here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

I just had this issue and it took me a little while to figure out.
I wrote a custom hook to get all the search params from the url.
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

function useGetAllSearchParams() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const params: { [anyProp: string]: string } = {};

  searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
    params[key] = value;
  });

  return params;
};

export default useGetAllSearchParams;

Usage in your component:
const allSearchParams = useGetAllSearchParams();

So if your url is /pathname?param1=lorem&param2=ipsum&param3=dolor&param4=sit
this function gives { param1: "lorem", param2: "ipsum", param3: "dolor", param4: "sit" }
to turn this into a url string you can use the function below:
export const buildQueryString = (obj: any) => {
  const queryString = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((key) => obj[key] !== "" && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== null)
  .map((key: string) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`)
  .join("&");

  return queryString;
};

Finally, to get the required string:
const requiredString = buildQueryString(allSearchParams);

console.log(requiredString) gives:
param1=lorem&param2=ipsum&param3=dolor&param4=sit


// ==== NEXT.JS ====
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    const { searchParams } = req.nextUrl
    const {
        address,
        startBlock,
        endBlock,
        sort,
        page,
        offset
    } = Object.fromEntries(searchParams.entries())


    if (!address) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Missing parameter "address"' }, { status: 400 })
    }

    const data = fn()

    return Response.json(data)
}

